# put tag on N'th item by using the asp:repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to put `<br>` tag only in front of 6th item.

how can I do this?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptWinner" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
     <%# GetWinnerID(Container.DataItem) %>
     </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptWinner" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <%# GetWinnerID(Container.DataItem) %>
         <%# Container.ItemIndex == 4 ? "<br />" : string.Empty %>
     </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

this adds `<br />` tag after the fifth element (in front of 6th).

Comment: @sunglim, yep, sure! `Container.DataItemIndex` is for `GridView` control. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to add a placeholder to hold the BR, or add a label.  Then you'll need to tie into the `OnItemDataBound` event and do checking:

```
protected void rptWinner_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Index == 6)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph = e.Item.FindControl("myPlaceholder") as PlaceHolder;
        ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
    }
}
```

Or something to that effect ;)